# Why doesn't my button change after clicking?

Tags: java, swing

Please help with the problem. I need the label to change to `X` after click on my button, and to `O` after the second click. Please check my code below, and tell me what is wrong? My program just changes the label to `X`, but doesn't change to `O` :(

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class test extends MouseAdapter {
    JPanel windowContent;
    JFrame frame;
    Button myButton;
    test() {
        windowContent = new JPanel();
        FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
        windowContent.setLayout(fl);
        
        myButton = new Button("Change text");
        myButton.addMouseListener(this);
        windowContent.add(myButton);
        
        frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
        frame.setContentPane(windowContent);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int i = 0;
        if (i == 0) {
            myButton.setLabel("X");
            i++;
        } else if (i == 1) {
            myButton.setLabel("O");
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your counter `i` is a local variable. Every `mouseClicked`-call has its own.

Comment: Initialize i outside of mouseClicked method.

Comment: yes, now all ok, thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Move out `i` from the function `mouseClicked`, put it in global space. It prevents resetting `i` value.
- I rename `i`, new name is `buttonStateChanger`
- Also, reset `buttonStateChanger` inside `else` block.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonTest extends MouseAdapter {
    JPanel windowContent;
    JFrame frame;
    Button myButton;
    int buttonStateChanger = 0;
    ButtonTest() {
        windowContent = new JPanel();
        FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
        windowContent.setLayout(fl);
        
        myButton = new Button("Change text");
        myButton.addMouseListener(this);
        windowContent.add(myButton);
        
        frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
        frame.setContentPane(windowContent);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        if (buttonStateChanger == 0) {
            myButton.setLabel("X");
            buttonStateChanger++;
        } else if (buttonStateChanger == 1) {
            myButton.setLabel("O");
            buttonStateChanger = 0;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ButtonTest();
    }

}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apart from your question, there are several other things in your code that I think need to be changed.

1. I don't know if it's a mistake or if it's intentional, but the type for variable `myButton` should be `javax.swing.JButton` and not `java.awt.Button` because you should, as much as possible, not mix AWT components with *Swing* components since *Swing* components are considered *lightweight* whereas AWT components are referred to as *heavyweight*. Refer to [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/mixing-components.html).
2. When using `JButton`, you should add an [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and not a `MouseListener`.
3. The default [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for `JPanel` **is** `FlowLayout` so no need to explicitly set it.
4. Rather than requiring a separate variable to record the number of times the `JButton` was clicked, I suggest using [client properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-).

Here is my rewrite of your `test` class that implements the above points. Note that I changed the name of the class from `test` to `Testing0`.

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Testing0 implements ActionListener {
    JPanel windowContent;
    JFrame frame;

    public Testing0() {
        windowContent = new JPanel();
        
        JButton myButton = new JButton("Change text");
        myButton.putClientProperty("count", Integer.valueOf(0));
        myButton.addActionListener(this);
        windowContent.add(myButton);
        
        frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
        frame.setContentPane(windowContent);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JButton) {
            JButton button = (JButton) source;
            Object value = button.getClientProperty("count");
            if (value instanceof Integer) {
                Integer objVal = (Integer) value;
                int intVal = objVal.intValue();
                String text = switch (intVal) {
                    case 0 -> "X";
                    case 1 -> "O";
                    default -> "";
                };
                button.setText(text);
                intVal = intVal == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                button.putClientProperty("count", Integer.valueOf(intVal));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new Testing0());
    }
}
```

Method `actionPerformed`, in the above code, uses [switch expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html) which were introduced in Java 12.

While not specifically stated in your question, the above code alternates the text of the `JButton`. If the text is `X` then it is changed to `O` when the button is clicked and if the text is `O` then it is changed to `X`. You can click the button as many times as you like and the text will change from `X` to `O` and back again.

Comment: Thank you, it is real important for me, because I only started learn java

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your `i` variable always set to 0 is that you initialize it in your `mouseClicked` function. So every time the function was called, you will always set the `i` to 0.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int i = 0;      //here is the problem
        if (i == 0) {
            myButton.setLabel("X");
            i++;
        } else if (i == 1) {
            myButton.setLabel("O");
        }
    }
```

Try to initialize it outside your `mouseClicked` function.